# MetaData Response - Broker hostname is wrong

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I use python-kafka's SimpleConsumer to listen to a topic in kafka broker. Kafka broker is running on a machine with its hostname as BROKER_HOST. 
 Now, SimpleConsumer requests for topic metadata from the broker BROKER_HOST for a topic TOPIC & gets a tuple

```
   (Broker metadata, Topic metadata)
```

Broker metadata comes as,

```
 {0: BrokerMetadata(nodeId=0, host='localhost', port=9092)}
```

and ideally, host value must be BROKER_HOST(`hostname` shell cmd confirms it) but it is localhost...

``How does the broker metadata for a topic get into kafka system? And obviously, this breaks the system since my consumer tries to connect to 9092 on its localhost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like your broker advertises itself incorrectly.

There's a line in your broker's `server.properties`:

```
#advertised.host.name=<hostname routable by clients>
```

You should uncomment it and set the value routable by your consumer and restart your broker.